# Calling public void method from Parent Window in UserControl button click event

Tags: c#, wpf, methods, parent-child

I have a `label` in my MainWindow navigation menu, and the content is binding to SQL command and that method is called `public void HBD_Count()`

I have various `UserControls` where on a `Button_Click` I would like to call `public void HBD_Count()` so that value in my `label` can be refreshed.

I tried called the `public partial class` from my MainWindow to my `UserControl` pages but it does  not work.

Here is my code in my Main Window, which populates the `label`:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;
        HBD_Count();
    }


        public void HBD_Count()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

            string selectQuery = ("SELECT COUNT(*) AS HBDCount FROM hb_Disputes WHERE (ASSGNTO = 'E099255') AND (STATUS = 3)");
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, connection);

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                HBD_Counts.Content = sqlReader["HBDCount"].ToString();
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

Here is my code in my `UserControl` page:

```
    public partial class Import_HighBill : UserControl
{
    public string ValueString { get; set; }
    public partial class MainWindow : Window { }

    public Import_HighBill()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AssignList();
    }
        private void butn_Assign_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINDOWS-B1AT5HC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CustomerRelations;Integrated Security=True;");

            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [hb_Disputes] SET ASSGNTO=@ASSGNTO WHERE DSP_ID=@DSP_ID", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DSP_ID", txt_ID.Text);
                // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATERSLVD", DBNull.Value);


                //  Analyst Name
                if (cmb_AnalystName.SelectedValue == null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ASSGNTO", DBNull.Value);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ASSGNTO", cmb_AnalystName.SelectedValue);
                }

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();



            // Here is where I am trying to call the method
               HBD_Count();




                // Clear Search Fields
                cmb_AnalystName.SelectedIndex = -1;
                MessageBox.Show("Dispute Assinged!!!");
                AssignList();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

    }
```

Comment: When you say it does not work, what do you mean by that.  Does it not compile, not update the label as you desired, or something else?

Comment: WPF was designed with the MVVM pattern in mind. This is clearly not MVVM. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about half the power and runs into problems at every other corner. I wrote a short intro into MVVM a few years back: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: @RobGoodwin I'm not able to call my method from the `UserControl` page I'm getting `The name HBD_Count does not exist in current context`

Comment: @Christopher Would you recommend rewriting all of my code for the application to align with the MVVM pattern?

Comment: @ethanjames.2342 Either alling your code to MVVM, or change your frontend to Windows Forms. I think the later is easier, as MVVM has quite the learning curve.

Comment: @ethanjames.2342  yes, the method you are trying to call is not a method on that user control class that you are calling it from, hence the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code to accomplish this task:

```
Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);
((MainWindow)parentWindow).HBD_Count();
```

The MVVM concept allows simplifying the task if you need to call different various methods. In this case you will need to include the method call inside the [Command](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/wpf-icommand-in-mvvm/) and will be able to access it using a [RelativeSource binding](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/relativesources-in-wpf/).

Comment: Thank you. I have a `Window` that I would like to call this method from and I tried using the same code but I'm receiving a `Unable to cast object type 'Application.Window1' to type 'Application.MainWindow` and I also tried using `((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).HBD_Count();` but was getting an similar message.

Comment: If you cannot access the target window this way, then you like need to store a reference to this window manually. In case of MVVM, this reference should be stored in the ViewModel. Without VM you can simply write it into the Tag property during creation of a new window. If you have a single MainWindow in your application you can also define a static property with this reference. In any case you will need to store it manually. I do not think that WPF provides you an alternative solution.